# Would + After + tense

Tags: tense

What tense should I use with after?

> I told you you wouldn't be surprised after I tell you this?
>
> I told you you wouldn't be surprised after I had told you this?
>
> I told you you wouldn't be surprised after I told you this?

Comment: I prefer your 2nd or 3rd alternants. You might say, though, that the perfect in the 2nd is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "after". I'd go for the 3rd one.

Comment: @BillJ The second sentence implies "You won't be surprised after I('ve)/('d) told you this." as the original. Would you use either of those sentences? In other words, is "After I('ve)/('d) told you this, you won't be surprised." an okay sentence (i.e., any of its three variations)?

Comment: I also would like to for for #3, this way: the sentence in the present tense has been this: *You won't be surprised after I tell you this.*, and its past tense form can be: *I told you that you wouldn't be surprised after I told you this.*

Comment: The 2nd and the 3th sound good for me, since you were talking about an action in the past, you must finish your sentence with the past perfect tense or simply the past tense. The 1st alternative would be acceptable if it were: _I told you, you will not be surprised after I tell you this._

Answer (score 1):

Your verb tense is governed by the previous verb tense

> I **tell** you you **won't be** surprised after I **tell** you.
>   I **told** you you **wouldn't be** surprised after I **told** you.

Either

> after I told you this
>   after I tell you this

are both acceptable and understandable.